# jQuery - issue trying to correctly use $(this)

Tags: jquery, html

[image]

I'm trying to use jQuery to go through each div with result-sold as a class.
scan through the 2 list items within them,

If the first list item is: "available online" 
and the second is: "Not available in stores."

Then select that second li and delete it.

[image]

```
<script>

$('div.result-sold').each(function() {
  $('.result-sold:contains("Available Online"):contains("Not Available In Stores")');
  $(this).$( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).css("list-style-image","none");

});

</script>
```

if you take `$(this)` out it will work - except on EVERY second list item across the page.

---

Using itsgoingdown's answer + an edit I have:

```
<script>     
$('div.result-sold').each(function() {

  if ($(this).find(':contains(Availabe online)') && $(this).find(':contains(Availabe online)').next(':contains(Not Available in stores)')) {

    $(this).find('li:contains(Not Available in stores)').remove();
  }
});

  $('div.result-sold').each(function() {

  if ($(this).find(':contains(Temporarily Sold Out Online)') && $(this).find(':contains(Temporarily Sold Out Online)').next(':contains(Available in stores)')) {

    $(this).find('li:contains(Temporarily Sold Out Online)').remove();
  }  
});
</script>
```

However it's removing "Temporarily Sold Out" from "Not Available in Stores" in stead of "Available in stores".

[image]

Comment: Yes as you are removing that in the last line.`$(this).find('li:contains(Temporarily Sold Out Online)').remove();`
Should you just remove .`$(this).find('li:contains(Available in stores)').remove();`  ?

Comment: No it's removing temp sold out online. when the case is to ONLY remove it when it finds "available in stores" in the picture above, it's "NOT available in Stores" and it is removing it from there.

but it will always remove it because "Not available in stores" always has "available in stores" make sense?

Comment: check the updated answer, and use both code snippets, for the previous and for later case, as I made some minor corrections. Let me know how it's going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 $('div.result-sold').each(function() {

 if($(this).find('li:contains("Available online")').length>0 && 
    $(this).find('li:contains("Available online")').next('li:contains("Not Available in stores")').length>0){   

        $(this).find('li:contains(Not Available in stores)').css("list-style-image","none");   

       }  
  });
```

In each `div.result-sold` if contains element with **Available online text**,which `next` element `contains` text **Not Available in stores**, then apply this `css` to the element containing **Not Available in stores** `(remove list image)`

Second part of the question, should check for exact text in if condition:

```
$('div.result-sold').each(function() {

 if($(this).find('li:contains("Temporarily Sold Out Online")').length>0 && 
     $(this).find('li:contains("Temporarily Sold Out Online")').next().text()==="Available in stores"){     

         $(this).find('li:contains("Temporarily Sold Out Online")').remove(); 
   }  
});
```

Check the **snippet below**

```js
$('div.result-sold').each(function() {


  if ($(this).find('li:contains("Available online")').length > 0 &&
    $(this).find('li:contains("Available online")').next('li:contains("Not Available in stores")').length > 0) {

    console.log("g");
    $(this).find('li:contains(Not Available in stores)').css("list-style-type", "none");

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result-product">
  <div class="result-sold">
    <ul>
      <li class="sold-instock">Available online</li>
      <li class="sold-not-sold">Not Available in stores</li>

    </ul>

  </div>

</div>


<div class="result-product">
  <div class="result-sold">
    <ul>
      <li class="sold-instock">Available online</li>
      <li class="in-stock">In stock</li>

    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
<div class="result-product">
  <div class="result-sold">
    <ul>
      <li class="sold-instock">Available online</li>
      <li class="sold-not-sold">Not Available in stores</li>

    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh i can definately do that - would you have the time to help me trouble shoot one more thing? it's traversing onto other divs and removing those list items as well.

Comment: I'm trying to do this use case now:
if ($(this).find(':contains(Temporarily Sold Out Online)') && 
$(this).find(':contains(Temporarily Sold Out Online)').next(':contains(Available in stores)')) {

    $(this).find('li:contains(Temporarily Sold Out Online)').remove();

  }

so it's working correctly - BUT seeing as i have the options: "Available in stores" and "Not available in stores" it breaks - because it's seeing "Not available" as "Available".

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware if the `$` function can be chained like that, but I expect not. The correct way to limit a selector to elements in a particular parent is to pass that parent as the second argument:

```
$( "ul li:nth-child(2)", this )
```

Since you need to filter by text as well, why not do it all in one step and get rid of the `each` also. something like:

```
$('div.result-sold li:contains("Available Online") + li:contains("Not Available In Stores")')
  .css("list-style-image","none");
```

Comment: Optionally you can chain with find, $( this ).find( "ul li:nth-child(2)" )

Comment: That makes it work - but it still selects every div's second list item as opposed to only the one that have "available online" "not available in stores".